# Is the Syntax for the Bash Script right for an if elif statement

Tags: bash, shell

I added another condition to my if, elseif condition for my bash shell script. I am new to shell scripting, can you guys review my code if my syntax for if conditions are right especially the "fi" implementation. Much appreciated.

```
    if [ -f /etc/system-release ] && grep Amazon /etc/system-release > /dev/null; then


cd /tmp
sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm

else
  # we're either RedHat or Ubuntu
  DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -is`
  DISTRIBUTOR2=`lsb_release -cs`

  if [ "trusty" == $DISTRIBUTOR2 ]; then

    cd /tmp         
    wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/debian_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.deb
    sudo dpkg -i amazon-ssm-agent.deb
    sudo start amazon-ssm-agent

   elif [ "RedHatEnterpriseServer" == $DISTRIBUTOR ]; then

    cd /tmp
    sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm

   elif [ "xenial" == $DISTRIBUTOR2 ]; then

    cd /tmp         
    wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/debian_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.deb
    sudo dpkg -i amazon-ssm-agent.deb
    sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
  fi


fi

sleep 10
```

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: You should put double quotes around variables in `[ ... ]`, like this: `if [ "trusty" == "$DISTRIBUTOR2" ]`

Comment: Using `==` in `[ ]` is actually not fully valid syntax. The POSIX-compliant string comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: That said, code reviews aren't what we do here -- there's actually a *separate* site for those, [codereview.se] SE. A question containing code should surround a specific error, with any content unrelated to that error removed. See the Help Center documentation on creating a [mcve].

Comment: When I execute the script, it says that "Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1"  it doesn't give me any specific error message. Any tips

Answer (score 0):

Looks basically ok, but https://www.shellcheck.net/ has a couple of comments that you should probably address.